# How to call a function in ASP.NET automatically after a certain time has elapsed?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, timer, delay, delayed-execution

Let's say I have a Label on my page. 
In PageLoad() it's Text parameter is set to "This is my first text".

After, for example, 1 minute I want this Label to change it's text parameter to "This is my second text" (completely automatically, without any interaction of a user with this site).

Any ideas are welcome. AJAX perhaps? How? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a timer like this:

http://dotnetperls.com/timer

Similar question on an AJAX version:

[ASP.NET/AJAX - Timer not working correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692769/asp-net-ajax-timer-not-working-correct)

Comment: tnx. I found a solution. I'll use AJAX timer control.